# How to set a very long title for a beamer presentation?

Tags: beamer, titles, beamerarticle

[image]Im using this [style](https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/presentations/delft-university-of-technology-beamer-presentation) for a beamer presentation, the problem is I would like to add a very long title but the title does not appear complete. So I tried this:

```
\title[title]{blablablablalbabllablba \par\noindent blablablablablablablablablablabal}
```

I also tried other several aproaches but dont get to set a large title, any idea of how to solve this issue?. Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: I also tried: `\\` and `\newline` but still can set this title in that style.

Comment: ` \\\` works for me, can you post a MWE?

Comment: @samcarter Thanks for the help. I all ready tried the ` \ ` but still dont get the title.

Comment: another idea would be `\linebreak`